# copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed) stops rest of function from executing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use the function `copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)` to copy a sheet in one file to another sheet in a different file while keeping everything, including column width, the same. Using just the function `copyTo(destination)`, my code works and I get everything I want in a different file, EXCEPT the column width. However, when I try and use `copyTo` with the `copyPasteType` argument, the sheet is copied perfectly (with the correct column widths), BUT any subsequent code isn't run. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

```
function createSpreadsheet(foldername) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(foldername);

  RESPONSE = FileName(); //a function that prompts the user for a filename

  //creates a new spreadsheet which has two sheets, and deletes the "Copy of Sheet1" sheet
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(RESPONSE);
  var newsheet = newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var copysheet = sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);
  sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);

  //when using CopyPasteType argument, everything from here down isn't run
  copysheet.getDataRange().copyTo(newsheet.getDataRange());
  copysheet.getDataRange().copyTo(newsheet.getDataRange(), 
  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(copysheet);

  var newSpreadsheetID = newSpreadsheet.getId();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheetID);
  folder.addFile(file); 
  DriveApp.removeFile(file);
  clearYellow(); //clears contents of yellow cells
  clearGray(); //clears contents of gray cells
}
```

I've also [asked this question in Google+](https://plus.google.com/114160934823386208913/posts/S3NDyRgnRLY)

Comment: If you run this script, I think that the error occurs at ``sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);``, because this cannot be used for Sheet. For ``copyTo()``, there are the method [``copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)`` of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-copypastetype-transposed) and the method [``copyTo(spreadsheet)`` of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)). If you had already known this error, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hmm, that might explain why everything below it doesn't work. However, the line you pointed out does actually work; if I just use copyTo(spreadsheet), then the column widths aren't preserved, but if I use copyTo(spreadsheet, copyPasteType, transposed), then the column widths are preserved. Also, I don't get an error message. The only problem is that for some reason using copyTo with three arguments stops the rest of my function from executing, but again, no error messages.

Comment: ``var copysheet = sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);`` works. But at ``sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);``, an error occurs. So could you please try to remove ``var copysheet = sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);`` and run ``sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);``.?

Comment: What do you find in your StackDriver logs for this particular script project?

Comment: This is script is local (that is, bound to the spreadsheet template), and so the StackDriver logs don't show anything (I don't think I even have access to them).

Comment: Tanaike, I tried what you suggested, and it didn't work. Nothing in the source sheet was copied over to the new sheet, and the new sheet wasn't placed in the folder I told the script to place it in. Also, it's not technically an error at that line per say, since script editor doesn't actually give me an error message and the script claims to have finished even though it doesn't execute anything after that line.

Comment: I'm really sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an answer as to why the copyTo with three arguments stopped the rest of my function from executing, but I found another way to copy the column widths over to the new spreadsheet that works.

```
function createSpreadsheet(foldername) {
  var oldspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var oldsheet = oldspreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(foldername);

  RESPONSE = FileName();

  //creates a new spreadsheet which has two sheets, and deletes the "Copy of Sheet1" sheet
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(RESPONSE);
  var newsheet = newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var copysheet = oldsheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);
  copysheet.getDataRange().copyTo(newsheet.getDataRange());

  var numberOfColumns = oldsheet.getLastColumn();
  for (columnNumber = 1; columnNumber <= numberOfColumns; columnNumber++){
    var Width = oldsheet.getColumnWidth(columnNumber);
    newsheet.setColumnWidth(columnNumber, Width);
  };

  newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(copysheet);

  var newSpreadsheetID = newSpreadsheet.getId();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheetID);
  folder.addFile(file); 
  DriveApp.removeFile(file);
  clearYellow(); //clears contents of yellow cells
  clearGray(); //clears contents of gray cells
}
```