# Google spreadsheet - treat "Ctrl + V" as "Ctrl + Shift + V"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to define for a spreadsheet that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (regular paste) will be treated as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (paste values only)? Not only for myself, but for any user that can edit.

Reason: The spreadsheet in question is filled with data validation, formatting and conditional formatting settings. Users use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> alot in this spreadsheet, so these settings are constantly being tampered with

Comment: This should be customized at OS level or keyboard level and not at Google sheets inside a browser.

Comment: I need to make the pre-defined settings of data validation and formatting resilient to the paste action. Any other ideas will be warmly accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am happy to update that I have achieved what I tried to achieve as follows:

1. Create a copy of the template spreadsheet, to serve solely as a design setting template.
2. Copy the relevant template sheet from the design setting template Ss into the destination spreadsheet (while keeping it hidden). This is acomplished using [copyTo of class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet).
3. Copy format, conditional formatting and data validation from template sheet to destination sheet. This is acomplished using [copyTo of class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed).
4. Deleting the tempalte (hidden) sheet from the destination spreadsheet.

**Note**: I included this function inside a library, as this should work in hundreds of spreadsheet copies.

**

## The fucntion

**:

```
function restoreRangeSettings(e) {
// retrieves data validation, conditional formatting and formatting settings from template
  var editedSs = e.source;
  var editedRange = editedSs.getActiveRange();
  var editedSh = editedRange.getSheet().getName();

  var templateSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('10zVclYTCEOEwskUID4vxSPxKR_tb3RaR76eG7TfxLUE');
  var templateSh = templateSs.getSheetByName(editedSh);
  var copiedSh = templateSh.copyTo(editedSs).hideSheet();
  var templateRange = editedSs.getSheetByName(copiedSh.getName()).getRange(editedRange.getA1Notation());

  templateRange.copyTo(editedRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
  templateRange.copyTo(editedRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING, false);
  templateRange.copyTo(editedRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION, false);

  editedSs.deleteSheet(copiedSh);
}
```

I relied heavily on the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137336/google-sheets-keep-formatting-when-coping-from-one-sheet-to-another).

[ziganotschka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11599789/ziganotschka), Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

> There is no direct way to achieve it, but as a workaround you can
>   attach to the spreadsheet an Apps Script with the following
>   functionality:

- The script contains an [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) function that fires automatically every time an edit to the sheet has been made (e.g. pasting)
- It detects the active range that has been edited
- It overwrites the contents of the active range with values only

Sample:

```
function onEdit(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var activeRange=spreadsheet.getActiveRange();
  activeRange.setValues(activeRange.getValues());
}
```

### UPDATE

If you want to paste `onEdit` the formatting, conditional formatting and data validation for the edited range from a template - you can use the method [copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed) spcifying the [copyPasteType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/copy-paste-type.html) accordingly.

Sample:

```
function onEdit(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var activeRange=spreadsheet.getActiveRange();
  var A1Notation=activeRange.getA1Notation();
  var templateRange=SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID OF THE TEMPLATE SPREADSHEET').getSheetByName('NAME OF THE TEMPLATE SHEET').getRange(A1Notation);
  templateRange.copyTo(activeRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT);
  templateRange.copyTo(activeRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING);
  templateRange.copyTo(activeRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION);
}
```

### Another option:

Use the method [copyFormatToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyFormatToRange(Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)):

```
function onEdit(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var activeRange=spreadsheet.getActiveRange();
  var A1Notation=activeRange.getA1Notation();
var templateRange=SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID OF THE TEMPLATE SPREADSHEET').getSheetByName('NAME OF THE TEMPLATE SHEET').getRange(A1Notation);
templateRange.copyFormatToRange(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet(), activeRange.getColumn(), activeRange.getColumn(), activeRange.getRow(), activeRange.getRow());
}
```

Comment: Hi ziganotschka, but doesn't it happen only after the paste action already overridden the previous conditional formatting/data validation settings (the settings that I am trying to keep untouched)?

Comment: For this you can use a workaround - for example have a secondary spreadsheet which is synced. Your users can paste any type of contents into the "dummy spreadsheet" and only the values will be transferred into the formatted and validated master spreadsheet. I wouldn't know of another possibility, since it is not possible to change the keyboard shortcuts for google documents: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4907911?hl=en

Comment: Thank you. The issue is that this feature is needed in multiple spreadsheets so I need it to be as elegant and compact as possible. I’m afraid that having a bunch of dummy spreadsheets is prone for problems

Comment: Would it be an option to you let the users submit their data via a Google Form?

Comment: This was my first idea, but the spreadsheet allows a much more flexible and fast filling of the data.

Comment: However, is it possible for the formatting, conditional formatting and data validation settings to be drawn from a template spreadsheet to multiple spreadsheet copies on edit (only for edited range)?

Comment: This is a good idea and it is possible! I will update my answer to show how you can do it.

Comment: Hi, I just tried it and the special pastings doesn't work for some reason. I tried to activate the script via an instalable on edit trigger and it still doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: addition: it's not that I get an error, but nothing happens

Comment: What do you mean by special pasting? You mean the script I provided you? You have to run it manually once (to trigger authorization flow) and thereafter it should work automatically (provided the edit takes place by a person and not by a script or formula update). You can implement some logs in the script to debug, otherwise I can have a look at your spreadsheet.

Comment: After getting the error report - I see the error is "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.”. I am not sure which part it refers to unfortunately.

Comment: This is not related to the code directly. The script might time out if you have a big amount of data. try to implement after every `templateRange.copyTo` request a `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`  statement. Have a look at the execution time of the script - make sure you do not surpass the maximum runtime limit of 6 min or other quota: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas. If you can not find the issue - let me have a look at your spreadsheet (remove sensitive personal information).

Comment: Thank you, The script fails after less than a second. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052408/copytodestination-copypastetype-transposed-stops-rest-of-function-from-execu

Comment: I cannot reproduce your server error, but I relaized that there is a typing mistake in my code - my bet - it should be `SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType` and not `spreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType`

Comment: If you keep getting the error  -try replacing the three `copyTo` statements through `templateRange.copyFormatToRange(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet(), activeRange.getColumn(), activeRange.getColumn(), activeRange.getRow(), activeRange.getRow())`

Comment: I really appreciate your patience.. I can't explain why, but no matter in what way I write the code- I simply can't get the action to excute. Furthermore- the script fails when the statements related to the copy are added. For the second option you suggested- the error is that both ranges should be in the same spreadsheet.

Comment: Did you try with a dummy sheet, to see if there is something wrong with the spreadsheet? Is it a problem for you if both ranges are in the same spreadsheet (can be different sheets, one of which can be hidden)?

Comment: Option 1 works if the template is a hidden sheet in the same spreadsheet. However - it is not optimale, as all of the hidden sheets might need manual updating in case of a change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205225/discussion-between-yaniv-aflalo-and-ziganotschka).